# how to get specific columns name from MYSQL

Tags: mysql

in MYSQL how to get specific columns name for example:
i have following cols in databse

```
ID
NAME
ADDRESS
MOBILE
```

below query shows all the above columns name but i want to get all cols except ID and MOBILE.

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM CONSIGNEE
```

Comment: Are you talking about select statement? use can use like this "select ID from tbname". Its pretty simple.

Comment: no i just want to get the columns name not data

Comment: Try : Select NAME,ADDRESS from CONSIGNEE

Comment: If you want to get list of columns for a given table you can query information_schema.columns table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `WHERE` to filter `FIELD` column

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM CONSIGNEE WHERE FIELD NOT IN ('ID', 'MOBILE')
```